# How to read the various field in from XML Tag by C#

Tags: xml

I have this below XML tag and want to read the fields  Pid , Kind via c# only.
please suggest how to do that ?

Comment: Could you post some code? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried and it worked . Thanks Ḟḹáḿíṅḡ Ⱬỏḿƀíé.

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Resource);
XmlNodeList nList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("OBJECT");
String Pid = ""; 
if (nList != null)
{
 foreach (XmlNode curr in nList)
 {
  string KindType = curr.Attributes["Kind"]?.InnerText;
  if( KindType.ToUpper() == "ANIMAL")
  {
   Pid = curr.Attributes["Pid"]?.InnerText;
   break;
  }
 }
}